# As a contractor, is it okay to list only the company where I work on LinkedIn?

Tags: professionalism, linkedin, professional-development

I'm a contractor working through an external agency.  Aside from the occasional reminder to submit my time sheet when I forget, I have almost no contact with the agency.  My supervisor continually reminds me and the other contractors that she considers us to be like any other team members.  The only perceivable difference between my status and that of my teammates is that my paycheck comes from a different source. The company where I work is a well-known international brand whereas the temp agency is, well, a temp agency. For obvious reasons, I would prefer my name be associated with the company people are more likely to be familiar with.

Is it necessary for me to list the name of the agency as my employer on LinkedIn rather than the company where I work?  Would it be seen as dishonest if I don't?

Comment: This might be a better duplicate: [Which company to mention in LinkedIn or resume: Actual Employer or the Client](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/49177)

Comment: if they are treating exactly  like an employee they run the risk of having to take you on as full time - which country is this?

Comment: I looked at one of my contractor friends profile recently, and he lists both his employment at his self owned firm and the contracts as jobs. He just puts that they are contracts in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Please discuss this with your customer. There are may be several factors, tho following of which come to my mind which would cause the agency or the customer not to like that

- legal issues (-> situation in Germany)
- Your customer being worried about you getting a target for phishing
- Your customer being worried about letting the world know for which areas they want external help right now (and how much).
- Your agency not wanting to show to whom they supply services
- Your agency not wanting you to make yourself a target for headhunters
- Possible future clients may prefer to avoid the impression of IP theft and not hire somebody from a competitor which they know.

Situation in Germany (IANAL):
There are laws in place which make a strict distinction between working as a contractor or as a leased worker. The latter implicates significantly stronger obligations and other legal limitations. The implications for a company if a court finds that a contractor works as a leased worker may be severe. Companies take great care that contractors appear very different from their internal employees, i.e. making sure that contractors do no appear to be bound in the company hierarchy.

Comment: if the OP is a contractor they have the right to market themselves shurely ?

Comment: I did not say if the need to stick what the customer or their agency says - i dont give legal advice -, however, listening what they want may be more appropriate than insisting on your right. I am very willing to not insist in every right which I have, if the customer behaves reasonably.

Comment: @Sascha could you provide a link with more info about the situation in Germany?