# Which company should I mention on my LinkedIn profile? The IT outsourcing consulting company or the actual client I will work for?

Tags: contracts, linkedin, consulting, outsourcing

So, here is my current situation: An US IT nearshore outsourcing company called “X” hired me (I live in Brazil, and I will work from home) to work as a contractor for them, and I will work as a software developer for a client of them (a big, California-based company called “Y”). As of now, there were no NDAs mentioned. Which company  (and how) would you guys suggest that I list on my LinkedIn and resume?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which company to mention in LinkedIn or resume: Actual Employer or the Client](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49177/which-company-to-mention-in-linkedin-or-resume-actual-employer-or-the-client)

Comment: Looking at the suggested question, it's not the same situation as the OPs question.

Comment: I put consulting company as the employer and "On-site assignment with Client Company" in job description.

Answer (score 1):

You don't work for the client, you work for the outsourcing company. That is what you should list.

You are performing work for the client, but you are not employed by the client, therefore you do not work for the client.

Comment: The outsourcing company is your employer, but you can say you worked on a contract supporting..

Answer (score 0):

Would you benefit more by mentioning company Y? Resume is just a starting point, you can get into more specific details during the interview stage. If you work with a lot of clients then it having them all under one umbrella company is easier.

Timeline also matters, without much context recruiters can see it as a red flag if you have only a couple of months of experience with each company there. If you’re going to be working with company Y for less than 4 months then don’t put it under their name.

You could also, and I don’t see why not, put both contractor experience with company X on the top and software engineer experience with Company Y below it on your resume.

(Just be careful, if you have confidentiality agreements)