# Issue with background check, what to do

Tags: job-offer, background-check

I have just been offered a graduate role which is conditional on passing a background check.

On my CV I have a tech company listed as my employer, but my contract was with another company who was employed by the aforementioned company. I was working in sales for them, selling the tech companies products, but it was very much organised through the tech company (meetings, trainings, etc.). This was only a part-time job and I worked for them for approximately 6 months.

The background checking company has contacted the tech company regarding past employment: I'm unsure as to whether they will have any record of me as my contract wasn't directly with them. My initial reference and the contact details I provided to the background checking company were for the company I had a contract with, but on my resume I had the tech companies name listed, as many people on LinkedIn and others I worked with had done the same.

What will happen if the tech company actually doesn't have a record of me working there? they should be aware that I was in the sales role for the other company but I'm not 100%.

I'm paranoid this will be grounds for revoking my offer, and I'm not sure what the best way to go about it would be. Did I make a mistake on my resume?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've removed the part asking for advice, since we don't really handle general advice, but I think the rest of your question can be answered.

Comment: For future reference: [How to list contracting on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/790/how-to-list-contracting-on-resume)

Answer (score 10):

**Don't freak out**, it's not the end of the world.

> What will happen if the tech company actually doesn't have a record of me working there?

You have two choices:

1. You can be proactive and reach out to them now and tell them that you were contracted out to Company A from Company C.
2. Only bring it up if they ask or mention it. It might seem a bit awkward, but it's not a huge issue.

> Did I make a mistake on my resume?

That is up for debate. The best way to avoid ambiguity like this is to include as many relevant details on your CV as possible. Perhaps mentioning in the work experience details that the work was contracted through Company C for Company A.

Comment: +1. I wrote in my CV like this: Place of work: Company A, in outsourcing by Company B.

Comment: I agree with Sonic and don't see the debatable part of this.  You worked for Company B.  The project was a contract with Company A.  Both names should be clearly on the resume.  not doing that is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

What companies are actually looking for – and why they engage these background-check companies – is:  ***falsification.***

If someone actually asks ... explain it to them, much as you just did for us here.  Don't be defensive – just tell the truth.

Yes, some "very-nice looking people" have absolutely no scruples about "lying through their teeth." (You *wouldn't* believe some of the things I've seen over the years ...)  Obviously, you aren't one of them.