# Can I list in my CV company that I work for, but not employed?

Tags: contractors, contracting

After graduation I was hired by big well-known international company (say "Company X") for an entry-level contractor position, that means that technically my employer is not Company X, but third-party staff agency (say "Company Y") and all my documents lists only Company Y (except non-disclosure policy agreement, to be more precise).

Am I eligible to put Company X in my CV? The reason is that I am actually working in X office, collaborate with X people and involved in X projects.

Comment: See also: [How to list contracting on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/790/how-to-list-contracting-on-resume)

Comment: As a contractor of \*ahem\* decades, it never occurred to me to state that it was contract work, and no one has ever mentioned or queried whether I was permanent or contract. What would it matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't lie. You are employed by Company Y. This doesn't mean you can't put Company X on your CV though, something like:

> - Jan 2018 - Present: Junior widget wrangler, Company Y (working exclusively onsite at Company X)

Of course assuming your NDA allows you to say this.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** - you'll want to make it clear that it is a contract position so as to avoid any potential confusion in background checks but from an experience point of view it's functionally equivalent to working there so that's what you put on your CV.